# Android Get switch from ActionLayout on Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android

How do I specifically get the switch from my actionLayout (that is a menu item) so I can set the 'setOnCheckedChangeListener' event?

Here is my menu for the navigation drawer:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <item android:id="@+id/nav_switch"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/action_view_switch"
            android:title="One-to-one mode" />
</menu>
```

With the action_view_switch actionlayout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/otoSwitch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

And finally, my navigation drawer:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nvView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"/>
```

I understand that I can do something like:

```
Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_switch);
View actionView = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
actionView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

  }
});
```

But this does not give me any states such as isChecked like 'setOnCheckedChangeListener' would.  How do I get the switch view so I can set its listeners?

Comment: You're nearly there - `Switch otoSwitch = (Switch) menuItem.getActionView().findViewById(R.id.otoSwitch);`.

Answer (score 7):

You've pretty much got it figured out, just a few more things. Here's what worked for me!

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/otoSwitch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

Next you get the view from the menu item.

```
Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
SwitchCompat actionView = (SwitchCompat) menu.findItem(R.id.nav_switch).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.ontoSwitch);
actionView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

  }
});
```

The reason I have another findViewById after the getActionView is because the getActionView will return a LinearLayout View and our switch is inside the LinearLayout so we just find the view id from the current LinearLayout returned to us, thus findItem(R.id.nav_switch).getActionView().findView... Hopefully this will help

Comment: This answer should be accepted, it's working as expected.